# Yii OAuth Implementation

Tags: php, oauth, yii, yii-extensions

Requiremen :- Yii, OAuth implemenation to authenticate and fetch user data.
I found out that there are two extensions. Eauth(support OAuth 2.0 and other social networking sites) and Eoauth(OAuth 1.0). Correct me If i am wrong.

I dont have to authenticate any social networking site. It's a different url from where I need to get the data.

Now i could successfully login and authenticate using "eoauth" extension but also I need to fetch information about the user. I don't find any function or way how to fetch data from url which lies under OAuth layer. Does Eauth or Eoauth supports fetching or it has to be custom coded ?
If this extensions does not do this then what is the other way I can authenticate and fetch data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Old but You just need to use CURL request to the end URL and you will get your data. I guess those modules doesn't have the function to fetch a data. I hope this might help you. I have used in one of my code and It was successful

```
public function GetData($url){
        $signatureMethod = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer,$this->token, 'GET',    $url, array());
        $request->sign_request($signatureMethod, $this->consumer, $this->token);        
        $fetchUrl = $request->to_url();
        $response = Yii::app()->CURL->run($fetchUrl);     
        return json_decode($response);               
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, Eauth supports fetching user's data. 
Let's see on Eauth structure. We have directories `/services`, `/custom_services` and class `EOAuthService`. EOAuthService contains method `makeSignedRequest()`, that return the protected resource from third-party site.

So, this method we can call from our serviceClass, that extends `EOAuthService`. For example, class `FacebookOAuthService` in `/services` directory. The class contains protected method `fetchAttributes()`, it calls method `makeSignedRequest($url)` and get $info (in JSON) from third-party site (FB in our example). Properties of this object - it's our user's data.
What about `/custom_services`? The directory contains classes for tuning our "BaseServiceClass".

So, for example, `CustomFacebookOAuthService` *extends* `FacebookOAuthService` *extends* `EOAuthService`.

You need create your own class, which will make signed request for your third-party site and get proper response (in JSON, for example). Then fetch gotten info - and voila!
Of course, user must be authenticated by third-party site for fine auth on your application through oauth.